# converting to double (error)

Tags: vb.net

i am converting a string to double

i would like to know in advanced whether it would case an error to convert a string to a double. for example if i try to convert "hello" to a double, it would give me an error.

is there a way for me to know ahead of time whether converting something will cause an error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want [Double.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1.aspx):

```
Dim PossibleDouble as Double
If Double.TryParse("hello", PossibleDouble) Then
  ''//Success!
Else
  ''//Not a double
End If
```

Comment: Note--the weird comment format is to fake-out the syntax highlighter

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, I see what you meant now.  The correct answer is TryParse as noted by Michael.

```
String string_val = 1.0;
double val;

val = System.Convert.ToDouble(string_val);
```